# Pandas how to vectorize this loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently trying to calculate the pnl of a portfolio and I am having difficulties thinking about a way to vectorize the following code

```
df_test_copy = df.copy()
df_test_copy['NV'] = 10000
df_test_copy['pnl'] = 0
last_nw = 10000
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    shares = last_nw / row['close_t+1']
    if row['pred_label'] == 2: # long
        pnl = (shares * row['close_t+16']) - (shares * row['close_t+1'])
        last_nw += pnl
        df_test_copy.loc[idx, 'pnl'] = pnl
    elif row['pred_label'] == 1:
        pnl = (shares * row['close_t+16']) - (shares * row['close_t+1'])
        last_nw -= pnl
        df_test_copy.loc[idx, 'pnl'] = -1*pnl
    df_test_copy.loc[idx, 'NV'] = last_nw
```

I feel like the only thing that is giving me struggle is the fact that `last_nw` information from the last iteration.

Edit: I added a reproducible example where the dataframe looks like this:

```
sample_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'open_time' : ['2022-08-16 07:20:00', '2022-08-16 07:21:00', '2022-08-16 07:22:00',
                    '2022-08-16 07:23:00', '2022-08-16 07:24:00', '2022-08-16 07:25:00',
                    '2022-08-16 07:26:00', '2022-08-16 07:27:00', '2022-08-16 07:28:00'],
     'pred_label' : [1, 1, 1,
                     2, 1, 1,
                     2, 0, 0],
     'close_t+1' : [1875.9, 1877.79, 1878.55,
                    1878.46, 1878.44, 1878.70,
                    1879.87, 1879.40, 1878.15],
     'close_t+16' : [1878.30, 1878.90, 1877.51,
                     1879.44, 1880.38, 1880.11,
                     1881.25, 1880.18, 1881.85]}
)
```

And as for the output it should look something like this:

[image: dataframe output]

Comment: To start, you can move `pnl =` out of the if-statement since it's the same in each branch and factor out `shares` into `pnl = shares * (row['close_t+16'] - row['close_t+1'])`, like Matmozaur wrote in [their answer](/a/77507567/4518341).

Comment: Oh wait, are there cases where `row['pred_label'] not in {2, 1}`? It'd help if you provided a [reproducible pandas example](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: @wjandrea just added an example in the original post

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341), post the text itself and use [code formatting](/editing-help#code) or [table formatting](/editing-help#tables).

Answer (score 0):

I think something like that could do the trick:

```
shares = 10000 / df['close_t+1']
long_condition = df['pred_label'] == 2
short_condition = df['pred_label'] == 1

df_test_copy['pnl'] = 0
df_test_copy.loc[long_condition, 'pnl'] = shares * (df.loc[long_condition, 'close_t+16'] - df.loc[long_condition, 'close_t+1'])
df_test_copy.loc[short_condition, 'pnl'] = -1 * shares * (df.loc[short_condition, 'close_t+16'] - df.loc[short_condition, 'close_t+1'])

df_test_copy['NV'] += df_test_copy['pnl'].cumsum()
```

Comment: it almost gives the solution, but here you assumed the numerator for shares is always 10000. This is what I was thinking before, but is there a way to vectorize is with the numerator of shares being the value of 'NV' in the previous row ?

Comment: I dont know if I understand correctly, but if you want to have previous value of NV instead of 1000 than you can replace
shares = 10000 / df['close_t+1']
with:
shares = df['NV'].shift(1) / df['close_t+1']
(You can also fill first field then with some value because it will be None)